# Consume a graphql endpoint from react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo

I am trying to consume the next Graphql endpoint:

[image]

I'm using react-apollo to consume this service from React, the next is the query:

```
import React from "react";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const getSpotsQuery = gql`
{
    spots{
      code
      name
      distance
      id  
    }
  }
`

export { getSpotsQuery };

And I'm trying to consume these query from the next hook:

import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';
import GridListTileBar from '@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar';
import ListSubheader from '@material-ui/core/ListSubheader';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import { getSpotsQuery } from '../../queries/queries';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  gridList: {
    width: 500,
    height: 450,
  },
  icon: {
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)',
  },
}));

const tileData = [
  {
    img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/943515859728896000/wrdqzQq5_400x400.jpg',
    title: 'Image',
    author: 'author',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/943515859728896000/wrdqzQq5_400x400.jpg',
    title: 'Que mira',
    author: 'author',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/943515859728896000/wrdqzQq5_400x400.jpg',
    title: 'jijue',
    author: 'author',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/943515859728896000/wrdqzQq5_400x400.jpg',
    title: 'Image',
    author: 'author',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/943515859728896000/wrdqzQq5_400x400.jpg',
    title: 'Image',
    author: 'caco',
  },
  {
    img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/943515859728896000/wrdqzQq5_400x400.jpg',
    title: 'Image',
    author: 'cat',
  }
];

const TitlebarGridList = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  console.log("las props:" + props)
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <GridList cellHeight={180} className={classes.gridList}>
        <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={2} style={{ height: 'auto' }}>
          <ListSubheader component="div">Spots</ListSubheader>
        </GridListTile>
        {tileData.map(tile => (
          <GridListTile key={tile.img}>
            <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
            <GridListTileBar
              title={tile.title}
              subtitle={<span>by: {tile.author}</span>}
              actionIcon={
                <IconButton aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`} className={classes.icon}>

                </IconButton>
              }
            />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    </div>
  );
}
export default graphql(getSpotsQuery)(TitlebarGridList)
```

The idea here is able to use the getSpotsQuery result from the TitlebarGridList using the props. But I am not able to achieve this, in the props I am getting the next value: [object Object]. I am not pretty sure if it is the correct way to implement this I am new using graphql from React.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you wrapped the root component in an `ApolloProvider` ?

Comment: Yes I wrapped the root component in a ApolloProvider.

Comment: `console.log(props.data)`? inspect component props with `react dev tools`